# How to set H.264 metadata in ffmpeg (fixed_frame_rate_flag)

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata, h.264

I would like to set the `fixed_frame_rate_flag` in the H.264 metadata so that [MediaInfo will report a constant frame rate](https://github.com/MediaArea/MediaInfo/issues/576) when scanning the file.

Supposedly I can set that flag using the bitstream filters. I tried adding `-bsf:v h264_metadata=fixed_frame_rate_flag=1` to the command but I get a lot of errors:

```
Error applying bitstream filters to an output packet for stream #0:0.
[h264_metadata @ 0x1887380] PPS id 0 not available.
[h264_metadata @ 0x1887380] Failed to write unit 0 (type 1).
[h264_metadata @ 0x1887380] Failed to write access unit into packet.
```

What is the correct way to set this flag in ffmpeg?

Here is the full command:

```
ffmpeg -loglevel info -y \
  -loop 1 \
  -framerate 25 \
  -i backgroundImage.png \
  -r 25 \
  -c:v libx264 -b:v 0.45M -threads 2 -x264opts keyint=5:min-keyint=5 -tune stillimage \
  -filter_complex \
  format=yuv420p,drawtext=fontfile='fonts/NotoSans-Bold.ttf':x=30:y=400:fontcolor=white:fontsize=100:text='%{pts\\:localtime\\:1689994200}' \
  -sws_flags bilinear \
  -bsf:v h264_metadata=fixed_frame_rate_flag=1 \
  -f mpegts -metadata service_name='Service01' -metadata service_name='DVStor' \
  -muxrate 0.65M \
  -t 15 \
  outputFile.ts
```

**EDIT I**

For further info, the output of the command **does output** constant frame rate; we created a 30min file and extracted the presentation timestamps and analyzed them in excel.  Every frame exactly 40ms spacing.

**EDIT II**

I'm not intimate with the MediaInfo code, but it would seem from `File_Avc.cpp:711` that VFR is declared if `timing_info_present_flag = 1` AND `fixed_frame_rate_flag = 0` is present in the stream.

```
//From vui_parameters
float64 PixelAspectRatio=1;
if ((*seq_parameter_set_Item)->vui_parameters)
{
  ....
    if ((*seq_parameter_set_Item)->vui_parameters->timing_info_present_flag)
    {
        if (!(*seq_parameter_set_Item)->vui_parameters->fixed_frame_rate_flag)
            Fill(Stream_Video, StreamPos_Last, Video_FrameRate_Mode, "VFR");
```

Comment: `fixed_frame_rate_flag` has nothing to do with "constant frame rate". FFmpeg documentation refers to H.264 section E.2.1 and table E-6. And the documentation says something related to HDR: *"fixed_frame_rate_flag equal to 1 indicates that the temporal distance between the HRD output times of any two
consecutive pictures in output order is constrained as follows. fixed_frame_rate_flag equal to 0 indicates that no such
constraints apply to the temporal distance between the HRD output times of any two consecutive pictures in output order."*

Comment: Yes, that's likely true. However, if `fixed_frame_rate_flag` is set to zero, then MediaInfo reports the stream as VFR and reports no numerical value for the frame rate.  Other tasks further down the workflow use MediaInfo to fetch the frame rate, which end up failing because no numerical fps value.

Comment: Mediainfo, IIRC, looks at the timestamps of the first 30 frames to determine stream CFRness. The bitstream flag is not looked at.

Comment: Hi Gyan, I looked into it, see above.  That might be true for other containers (maybe?) but best I could find is the code snippet above: VFR is a function of `timing_info_present_flag` and `fixed_frame_rate_flag`. Anyway to set that flag in ffmpeg?